# Xcode 7 beta 3's builds are much larger than Xcode 6's

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

Using Xcode 6, I was seeing a build size for a project of 5MB. With Xcode 7, with no library changes, but with the migration from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2, the build size has increased to 22MB. Has anybody else encountered this issue, and can we expect this to get smaller with future betas, or are there manual steps to be taken?

The project uses CocoaPods, with 8 included dependencies and `ENABLE_BITCODE` turned off (due to various dependencies not yet supporting this).

Comment: Have you compared the app bundle contents?  Does the Swift 1.2 project include the `libswiftxxx.dylib` files that the Swift 2 project does?

Comment: Thanks @trojanfoe. :)